# Openfeint 2.4.10 eating CPU usage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, openfeint

i noticed that openfeint is eating up my iphone cpu usage. My game slowed down after i updated to the latest openfeint. I ran the instruments cpu sampler and it showed that that openfeint was eating up to 65% of the cpu usage and that made my game very unresponsive. Anyone else noticed that as well?

Answer (score 0):

From what the opeinfeint team told me, it is normal that it takes  65% reported cpu usage.